# working in jupyter notebooks attempting to work with the tkinter module. printing a rectangle on a canvas(new shell) but a new screen does not appear

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am a noob, so I do not know what the problem is.

```py
from tkinter import *
tk= Tk()
canvas= Canvas(tk, width= 400, height= 400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,50,50)
```

Comment: You need to call `tk.mainloop()` at the end.